# Fetch method for BST returning null

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have gone over my code for most of the day, and I cannot figure out why my BST isn't populating.  I have included all of the code below, however, the specific issue lies with the fetch method returning null in all cases except Will and Ted.  When I invoke fetch for any list other than Will or Ted, a null is returned.  I do not know if the issue lies in fetch or findNode().

```
package binarysearchtree;


 public class SearchTree
 {   TreeNode root;
 public Listing compare;
 public int i = 1;
     public SearchTree()
     {  root = null;
     }
     public boolean insert(Listing newListing)
     {  TreeNodeWrapper p = new TreeNodeWrapper();
        TreeNodeWrapper c = new TreeNodeWrapper();
        TreeNode n = new TreeNode();
        compare = newListing;
       if(n == null)// out of memory
          return false;
       else // insert the node
       {  n.node = newListing.deepCopy(); // fill in the TreeNode's fields
          n.lc = null;
          n.rc = null;
          if(root == null) // tree is empty
          {  root = n; }
          else
          {  findNode(newListing.getKey(), p, c); // find the node's parent
             if(newListing.getKey().compareTo(p.get().node.getKey()) < 0) 
                  p.get().lc = n; // insert new node as a left child
             else
                  p.get().rc = n; // insert new node as a right child
          }
          return true;
       }
    } // end insert method
    public Listing fetch(String targetKey)
    {  boolean found;
       TreeNodeWrapper p = new TreeNodeWrapper();
       TreeNodeWrapper c = new TreeNodeWrapper();
       found = findNode(targetKey, p, c); // locate the node
       if(found == true)
          return c.get().node.deepCopy();
       else
          return null;
    } // end of fetch method
    public boolean delete(String targetKey)
    {  boolean found;
       TreeNodeWrapper p = new TreeNodeWrapper();
       TreeNodeWrapper c = new TreeNodeWrapper();
       TreeNode largest;
       TreeNode nextLargest;
       found = findNode(targetKey, p, c);
       if(found == false) // node not found
          return false;
       else // identify the case number
        {  if(c.get().lc == null && c.get().rc == null) // case 1: deleted
                                                      // node has no
                                                      // children
           {  if(p.get().lc == c.get()) // deleted node is a left child
                p.get().lc = null;
              else                      // deleted node is a right child
               p.get().rc = null;
          } // end case 1
          else if(c.get().lc == null || c.get().rc == null) // case 2:
                                                           // 1 child
          { if(p.get().lc == c.get()) // deleted node is a left child
            { if(c.get().lc != null) // deleted node has a left child
                 p.get().lc = c.get().lc;
              else
                 p.get().lc = c.get().rc;
            }
            else                     // deleted node is a right child
            {  if(c.get().lc != null) // deleted node has a left child
                  p.get().rc = c.get().lc;
               else
                  p.get().rc = c.get().rc;
            }
          } // end case 2
          else // case 3: deleted node has two children
         {  nextLargest = c.get().lc;
            largest = nextLargest.rc;
            if(largest != null) // left child has a right subtree
            {  while(largest.rc != null) // move down right subtree
               {  nextLargest = largest;
                  largest = largest.rc;
               }
               c.get().node = largest.node; // overwrite deleted node
               nextLargest.rc = largest.lc; // save the left subtree
            }
            else // left child does not have a right subtree
            {  nextLargest.rc = c.get().rc; // save the right subtree
               if(p.get().lc == c.get()) // deleted node is a left child
                  p.get().lc = nextLargest; // jump around deleted node
               else                   // deleted node is a right child
                  p.get().rc = nextLargest; // jump around deleted node
            }
         } // end of case 3
       return true;
     }
  } // end of delete method
  public boolean update(String targetKey, Listing newListing)
  {  if(delete(targetKey) == false)
        return false;
        else if(insert(newListing) == false)
             return false;
        return true;
     } // end of update
     public class TreeNode
     {  private Listing node;
        private TreeNode lc;
       private TreeNode rc;
       public TreeNode()
       {
       }
    } // end of class TreeNode
    private boolean findNode(String targetKey, TreeNodeWrapper parent,
                          TreeNodeWrapper child)
    {  parent.set(root);
       child.set(root);
       if(root == null) // tree is empty
           return true;
       while(child.get() != null)              
       {  
           if(child.get().node.compareTo(targetKey) == 0){ // node found 
               System.out.print("We finally found one!!!!!\n");
            return true;
           }
          else
          {  parent.set(child.get());
             if(targetKey.compareTo(child.get().node.getKey()) > 0) {
                 System.out.print(child.get().node.getKey() + "\n");
                 child.set(child.get().lc);
             }
             else {
                                      System.out.print(child.get().node.getKey() + "\n");

                child.set(child.get().rc); 
             }
          }


       } // end while
       return false;
    } // end of findNode
    public class TreeNodeWrapper
    {  TreeNode treeRef = null;
       public TreeNodeWrapper()
       {
       }
       public TreeNode get()
       {  return treeRef;
       }
       public void set(TreeNode t)
       {  treeRef = t;
       }

    } // end of class TreeNodeWrapper
 } // end class BinaryTree
```

The class "Listing"

```
package binarysearchtree;

public class Listing
 {  private String name;  // key field
    private String address;
    private String number;
    public Listing(String n, String a, String num)
    {  name = n;
       address = a;
       number = num;    
    }
   public String toString()
   {  return("Name is " + name +
      "\nAddress is " + address +
      "\nNumber is " + number + "\n");
   }
   public Listing deepCopy()
   {  Listing clone = new Listing(name, address, number);
      return clone;
   }
   public int compareTo(String targetKey)
   {  return(name.compareTo(targetKey));
   }
   public void setAddress(String a) // coded to demonstrate
                                       // encapsulation
   {  address = a;
   } // end of setAddress method
       public String getKey() 
   {    
       return name;
   }

 } // end of class Listing
```

and finally my main method:

```
package binarysearchtree;

import binarysearchtree.BinaryTree.TreeNode;

public class BinarySearchTree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SearchTree t = new SearchTree();
        Listing l;
        Listing l1 = new Listing("Ann",     "1st Avenue", "111 1111");
        Listing l2  = new Listing("Bill",     "2nd Avenue",   "222 2222");
        Listing l3  = new Listing("Carol",    "3rd Avenue",   "333 3333");
        Listing l4  = new Listing("Mike",     "4th Avenue",   "444 4444");
        Listing l5  = new Listing("Pat",      "5th Avenue",   "555 5555");
        Listing l6  = new Listing("Sally",    "6th Avenue",   "666 6666");
        Listing l7  = new Listing("Ted",      "7th Avenue",   "777 7777");
        Listing l8  = new Listing("Vick",     "8th Avenue",   "888 8888");
        Listing l9  = new Listing("Will",     "9th Avenue",   "999 9999");
        Listing l10 = new Listing("Zack",     "11th Avenue",  "101 0101");
        Listing l11 = new Listing("Zeek",     "12th Avenue",  "121 2121");

        //insert nodes
        t.insert(l9);
        t.insert(l7);
        t.insert(l10);
        t.insert(l2);
        t.insert(l8);
        t.insert(l1);
        t.insert(l4);
        t.insert(l3);
        t.insert(l6);
        t.insert(l5);
        //fetch nodes
        System.out.println(t.fetch("Carol"));
        System.out.println(t.fetch("Sally"));
        System.out.println(t.fetch("Ted"));
        // delete nodes
        t.delete("Carol"); // a node with NO children
        System.out.println(t.fetch("Carol"));
        t.delete("Sally"); // a node with ONE child
        System.out.println(t.fetch("Sally"));
        t.delete("Ted"); // a node with TWO children
        System.out.println(t.fetch("Ted"));
        // update nodes
        t.update("Bill", l3);
        System.out.println(t.fetch("Carol"));
        System.out.println(t.fetch("Bill"));
        System.out.print(l1.getKey());
        System.exit(0);


    }

}
```

Comment: so what, you want US to debug it for ya?

Comment: You're going to need to debug this to narrow the issue down a little. Most aren't too enthused to rummage through code to find the problem.

Comment: Remove delete calls from the main method. Does insert work properly? If yes, your problem lies in delete method, and title of the question (along with many other things) should be updated. It's never a good idea to test many things a once.

Comment: The specific problem, I think, lies in the fetch method.  When I test insert method, I can print each of the values going into the BST.  I cannot use the fetch method to extract them.  I only receive a List from fetch when I call either Will or Ted, any other call returns null.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out.